# Slide up animation for fragment

Tags: android-fragments

how can slide up animation for fragment be implemented?
i have an activity  which contains two fragments A and B resp. A on left and B on right. Initially only B is visible. There is a button on B. When clicked, the fragment A should slide up from the bottom of the screen. When the button is clicked again, the fragment A should slide down. 
how can this animation if fragment be achieved?